# auto scroll: stop jumps back to top of page

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have a page in which the user clicks one link to start scrolling down the page automatically for ease in reading. There is another link the user clicks to stop the scrolling. The former works perfectly, but the latter makes the page jump back to the top when clicked instead of stopping the scrolling at the that place on the page. Any ideas?

```
function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0,1); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
    scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',50); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
}
function stopScroll() {
    clearTimeout(scrolldelay);
}
```

I tried to add `return false;` to the second function from something I read on another post, but it didn't help. I don't fully understand the use of return anyhow. Thanks for any help.

Comment: your `scrolldelay` variable can't be accessed in another function.

Comment: Why @ChasingDeath it appears to be global to me.

Comment: Hey @preahkumpii, show how you are calling these functions. Is there any errors in the console?

Comment: The calls were done exactly as @Delan described in the answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that you're doing something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="pageScroll();">start</a>
<a href="#" onclick="stopScroll();">stop</a>
```

The quickest fix is to return false from the `onclick` event handlers, like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="pageScroll(); return false;">start</a>
<a href="#" onclick="stopScroll(); return false;">stop</a>
```

The idea is to stop the browser from doing the default action of the event (in this case, going to `#`, which scrolls to the top of the page). Nowadays, the more modern way is to bind an event handler function, then use `e.preventDefault()` in it, but `return false;` still works for old-style event attributes.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. Worked perfectly. I understand what you said about not allowing the link to go to the default action, but how does `return false` prevent that?

Comment: There isn't really a "reason", but one way that historically, the DOM allows event handlers to cancel the default action (before `.preventDefault()` was introduced) is to return false from the handler function (in this case, the handler function is the `onclick` string.